# How to cause .NET to save a TIFF in PARGB32 format?

Tags: c#, .net, tiff, premultiplied-alpha

I have created a bitmap in PARGB32 format. I realize PNG cannot store premultiplied alpha (at least, marked as such), but I believe TIFF can. How can I force .NET to save a TIFF in PARGB32 format? By default, it appears to load back as AGRB32, even if the bitmap being saved is in PARGB32 format.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat(v=vs.110).aspx) you could use the `PixelFormat` enum.

A quick and dirty example could be:

```
var converted = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(converted))
{
    g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
}
IntPtr menuBmp = bmp.GetHbitmap();
```

This is assuming a variable called bmp hold the image.